# Get notified when companies post new jobs

Tags: web-apps, notification

Are there webapps where you:

- follow a list of companies where you'd like to
- optionally, put some filters (location, job title...)

The webapp then monitors these companies' careers page, and sends you an email when there's a match.

Something like Linkedin's job alerts, but I don't use LinkedIn, would rather have a separate webapp.

Comment: I don't think there are many if any that "monitor pages", but there are a lot where companies post jobs either manually or through API.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, as far as I know. However, you could turn [Google custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to partially fulfill your purpose. Add the links to the career pages for the companies you might apply to, with key words indicating suitable occupations and working locales.

You would need to run the search every day or two and then weed out jobs you had already seen.